# When emulating Android API 30(R), with latest ARCore 1.17.0 installed, AR apps don't work

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, arcore, android-11

Is the problem in the Android API 30 or the ARCore?
Video: https://youtu.be/6xKQb-FrYxU

Comment: had a similar issue. The ArCoreApk class tells me that ArCore on the device is outdated.